# Mysql timeout error handling

Tags: php, mysql, performance, web-services, mysql-error-1064

I am getting data from a web service and some times mysql times out  "mysql server has gone away"  and the whole page crashes.Is there any way I can capture such kind of error and not show the user a blank screen with the error message but instead redirect to some other page ... (programming language used is  PHP)

Comment: Have you tried to use [`mysqli_ping()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php) or something similar?

Comment: Are You queries complex?

Comment: Do you have access to mysql? If so, you could try increasing mysql timeout limit.

Comment: yes there are quite a lot of queries running its a booking engine with multi supplier... I am trying to optimize the queries bit for the time being just want to trap the error and not show the client if it happens ..